# Issue in Handle IE Download popup in Selenium Java.Tried Using Robot class and AutoIT which it fails when system is Locked or idle

Tags: java, powershell, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We are working on a SELENIUM test case that has to download a file from web application. This app works only in IE so we need to handle download popup. To handle this we have Robot class which worked perfectly. Unfortunately this fails when the machine is locked or idle. So we moved to AutoIT which also fails when the machine is locked or idle.

Issue now is both works fine when machine is active.

Is there any alternate way to handle this action ?? We tried using powershell script to perform keyboard action which is also not recognize.

Looking for suggestion

Please do not refer sikuli as it is restricted in our project due to some security purpose

Comment: Can you use any other browser? IE is pretty old.

Comment: Selenium (or any script at all) can not handle OS dialogs, it would be a huge security issue. The only way is to avoid appearing the pop-up. I'm not sure if IE can autodownload files based on file type like Firefox or Chrome does.

Comment: The sad part here is, our app does not support other browsers.